# I'm having trouble rendering my player sprite while doing the Real Python pygame primer

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm currently going through [Real Python's pygame primer](https://realpython.com/blog/python/pygame-a-primer/#.Vo0sHqOmRRI.reddit) and I can't seem to render the player sprite. Here's the code I have:

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.surf.fill((225, 225, 225))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right < 800:
            self.rect.right = 0
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom < 600:
            self.rect.bottom = 600

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20,10))
        self.surf.fill((225, 225, 225))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center= (820, random.randint(0, 600)))
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 2)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 500)

player = Player()

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((0, 0, 0))

enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE or event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
        elif(event.type == ADDENEMY):
            new_enemy = Enemy()
            enemies.add(new_enemy)
            all_sprites.add(new_enemy)
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)
    enemies.update()
    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is almost exactly what they have as an example in the tutorial (I made a few tweaks in values), but when I run the program the player sprite is not rendered. I'm not sure why because it is clearly added to my all_sprites group that gets blit every loop. I've gone through the code forwards and backwards and can't find the issue. This is my first question so please let me know what other information to include next time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't see your sprites on the screen it's sometimes useful to print out the current position by simply calling

```
print self.rect
```

inside the `player`'s `update()` method.

This currently this yields you

```
<rect(-50, 550, 50, 50)>
```

which represents the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` of the rect and ie. of the sprite.

Because the `update()` method of the `Player` class is the only part in your program where you set this parameters, you know that there might be some errors: Instead of setting the `pygame.Rect` attributes `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` to the maximum screen size to keep them showing on the users display you positioned the player at `-50, 550` from the sett-up.

This is because you alternated `<` and `>` and mixed up some numbers:

```
if self.rect.left < 0:
   self.rect.left = 0
if self.rect.right < 800:
   self.rect.right = 0

if self.rect.top < 0:
   self.rect.top = 0
if self.rect.bottom < 600:
   self.rect.bottom = 600
```

should be

```
if self.rect.left < 0:
    self.rect.left = 0
if self.rect.right > 800:
    self.rect.right = 800

if self.rect.top < 0:
    self.rect.top = 0
if self.rect.bottom > 600:
    self.rect.bottom = 600
```

Now your program should run as expected.